# Handle several chained-function with python multiprocessing (pool)

Tags: python, string, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Coding is pretty new for me, so don't mind me if what I'm asking is quite easy or idiotic.

I wrote a python script for doing some obscure stuff, long story short, I'm trying to compare some strings from similar objects from 4 different files.

First I need to fetch the objects in each file, then transform the part of the object which I'm interested in, in a format I can compare them, then compare, and finally write the results in a file.

Unfortunately, it is super slow. I know where my bottleneck steps are (the object transformation part, function2()), I would like to improve the speed of my program with some multiprocessing.

I tried several things, the only one I managed to get working is the pool function.

So I made a big function summarising all my steps and try to make it works with pool workers.

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def function1(name_object,input):

    fetch the objects in input
    return objects

def function2(objects) :

    transforming the objects into strings
    return strings

def function3(strings,output) :

    compare each position of the strings
    outptut.write(results)

def function_finale(name_object,input,output) :
    objects = function1(name_object,input)
    strings = function2(objects)
    results = function3(strings,output)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)

    [pool.apply_async(combine, args=(object,file)) for object in file]
```

(Un)surprisingly the pool workers terminate the function after the first subfunction. I think I can do parallel programming, because my objects can be handled separately, asynchronously in any order, but the order of my functions must be followed once an object is fetched.

Basically, I would like to handle several objects in the same time in my loop with several processes! It should be possible, right?

I got some constraint, for example, I cannot stock everything in the dictionary because I got 300k+ objects which are pretty heavy (indeed, I'm doing this because of memory issues first).

Any advice?

Cheers.